# Reorganizing Ruby array into hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array of `Products`, each of which has a name and a category. I would like to produce a hash in which each key is a category string and each element is a product with that category, akin to the following:

```
{ "Apple" => [ <Golden Delicious>, <Granny Smith> ], ...
  "Banana" => ...
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8):

In 1.8.7+ or with active_support (or facets, I think), you can use group_by:

```
products.group_by {|prod| prod.category}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
h = Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = []}
products.each {|p| h[p.category] << p}
```

Answer (score 1):

The oneliner

```
arr = [["apple", "granny"],["apple", "smith"], ["banana", "chiq"]]
h = arr.inject(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}) {|ha,(cat,name)| ha[cat] << name; ha}
```

:-)

But I agree, #group_by is much more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

```
# a for all
# p for product
new_array = products.inject({}) {|a,p| a[p.category.name] ||= []; a[p.category.name] << p}
```

Comment: You're missing ";a" from the end of your inject block -- the block has to return the memo hash.

Comment: thanks for the note! but doesn't last expression return the hash?

Comment: No, it returns the a[p.category.name] array (the result of the Array#<< method)

Comment: A slightly shorter version using inject: products.inject(Hash.new([])) {a[p.category.name] += [p]; a}